# Cluster text documents in database

Tags: postgresql, data-mining, text-mining, document-classification

I do have 20.000 text files loaded in PostgreSQL database, one file in one row, all stored in table named `docs` with columns `doc_id` and `doc_content`.

I know that there is approximately 8 types of documents. Here are my questions:

- How can I find these groups?
- Are there some similarity, dissimilarity measures I can use?
- Is there some implementation of longest common substring in PostgreSQL?
- Are there some extensions for text mining in PostgreSQL? (I've found only [Tsearch](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/wiki/Tsearch2), but this seems to be last updated in 2007)

I can probably use some `like '%%'` or `SIMILAR TO`, but there might be better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch.html), which is part of PostgreSQL 9.x core (aka Tsearch2).

For some kind of measure of longest common substring (or similarity if you will), you might be able to use `levenshtein()` function - part of [`fuzzystrmatch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) extension.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a clustering technique such as K-Means or Hierarchical Clustering.
2. Yes you can use the Cosine similarity between documents, looking at the binary term count, term counts, term frequencies, or TF-IDF frequencies.
3. I don't know about that one.
4. Not sure, but you could use R or RapidMiner to do the data mining against your database.